# Perl Cryptology: Encrypting/Decrypting ASCII chracters with pack and unpack functions

Tags: perl, encryption, cryptography, ascii, unpack

I need help figuring out how these two subroutines work and what values or data structures they return. Here's a minimal representation of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

# an array of ASCII encrypted characters
my @quality = ("C~#p)eOA`/>*", "DCCec)ds~~", "*^&*"); # for instance

# input the quality
# the '@' character in front deferences the subroutine's returned array ref 
my @q = @{unpack_qual_to_phred(@quality)};

print pack_phred_to_qual(\@q) . "\n";

sub unpack_qual_to_phred{
    my ($qual)=@_;
    my $upack_code='c' . length($qual);
    my @q=unpack("$upack_code",$qual);
    for(my $i=0;$i<@q;$i++){
        $q[$i]-=64;
    }
    return(\@q);
}

sub pack_phred_to_qual{
    my ($q_ref)=@_;
    @q=@{$q_ref};
    for(my $i=0;$i<@q;$i++){
        $q[$i]+=64;
    }
    my $pack_code='c' . int(@q);
    my $qual=pack("$pack_code",@q);

    return ($qual);
}


1;
```

From my understanding, the `unpack_qual_to_phread()` subroutine apparently decrypts the ASCII character elements stored in `@quality`. The subroutine reads in an array containing elements of ASCII characters. Each element of the array is processed and apparently decrypted. The subroutine then returns an array ref containing elements of the decrypted array. I understand this much *however* I'm not really familiar with the Perl functions `pack` and `unpack`. Also I was unable to find any good examples of them online.

I think the `pack_phred_to_qual` subroutine converts the quality array ref back into ASCII characters and prints them.

thanks. any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Also if someone could provide a simple example of how Perl's `pack` and `unpack` functions work that would help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating the length is needless. Those functions can be simplified to

```
sub unpack_qual_to_phred { [ map $_ - 64, unpack 'c*', $_[0] ] }
sub pack_phred_to_qual { pack 'c*', map $_ + 64, @{ $_[0] } }
```

In encryption terms, it's a crazy simple substitution cypher. It simply subtracts 64 from the character number of each character. It could have been written as

```
sub encrypt { map $_ - 64, @_ }
sub decrypt { map $_ + 64, @_ }
```

The pack/unpack doesn't factor in the encryption/decryption at all; it's just a way of iterating over each byte.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how the `unpack` and `pack`functions work. In the example I posted above, the first element processed by `unpack("c12", "C~#p)eOA'/>*")` which stores the value into `@q` Can you tell me the value of the first element stored in `@q`? I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: For byte 67, which is "C" in ASCII, `unpack C` returns 67.

Comment: Regarding `unpack("c12", C~#p)eOA'/>*`, `c12` is the TEMPLATE and `C~#p)eOA`/>*` is the EXPRESSION. What does the TEMPLATE `c12` really mean?

Comment: `c12` means `cccccccccccc`. Could also have been written `c*`. Repeat above for the next 11 bytes.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. please bare with me, I haven't learned about ASCII characters or binary representation in any of my university CS courses yet. What does gets repeat above for the next 11 bytes? Also, how does the TEMPLATE work in the unpack function? Lastly, how does it tell the function to format the EXPRESSION?

Comment: Ah okay I think @Joe explained this part. Thanks everyone for helping me out!

Comment: The computer doesn't know anything about letters. There's an understanding that 65 means "A" in certain cirumstances. That understanding is called the ASCII encoding. Many other encodings (ways of representing letters with numbers) exists, but most are extensions of ASCII.

Comment: `TEMPLATE` doesn't "work". It tells `unpack` and `pack` what to do. The details are in the documentation. What `EXPRESSION` are you talking about? That term isn't used in the docs like that.

Answer (score 3):

It is fairly simple, as packs go.  Is is calling `unpack("c12", "C~#p)eOA`/>*)` which takes each letter in turn and finds the ascii value for that letter, and then subtracts 64 from the value (well, subtracting 64 is a post-processing step, nothing to do with pack).  So letter "C" is ascii 67 and 67-64 is 3.  Thus the first value out of that function is a 3.  Next is "~" which is ascii 126.  126-64 is 62.  Next is # which is ascii 35, and 35-64 is -29, etc.

The complete set of numbers being generated from your script is:

3,62,-29,48,-23,37,15,1,32,-17,-2,-22

The "encryption" step simply reverses this process.  Adds 64 and then converts to a char.

Comment: Regarding `unpack("c12", C~#p)eOA'/>*`, `c12` is the TEMPLATE and `C~#p)eOA`/>*` is the EXPRESSION. What does the TEMPLATE `c12` really mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer to your question, but did you read [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html)? Or the [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)/[unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) docs on [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/index.html)? Those will probably go a long way to helping you understand.

EDIT:

Here's a simple way to think of it: say you have a 4-byte number stored in memory, 1234. If that's in a perl scalar, $num, then

```
pack('s*', $num)
```

would return

```
π♦
```

or whatever the actual *internal storage* value of "1234" is. So `pack()` treated the scalar value as a string, and turned it into the actual binary representation of the number (you see "pi-diamond" printed out, because that's the ASCII representation of that number). Conversely,

```
unpack('s*', "π♦")
```

would return the string "1234".

---

The `unpack()` part of your `unpack_qual_to_phred()` subroutine could be simplified to:

```
my @q = unpack("c12", "C~#p)e0A`/>*");
```

which would return a list of ASCII character pairs, each pair corresponding to a byte in the second argument.

Comment: thanks for the links @Joe. I glanced over those web pages earlier today but I think the examples they provided confused me even more.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I have a two questions: Is the binary representation the same as the ASCII representation? Another question: in the example you provided `unpack('s*', "π♦")`, `'s*'` is the TEMPLATE. How does the TEMPLATE work in the unpack function? How does it tell the function to format `π♦`?

Comment: No, the binary representation is different. Say the actual bits stored in a byte RAM are 01010100. The decimal value is 84. But the ASCII representation of that byte is "T" (see www.asciitable.com). The actual value of the byte of RAM is the same -- we're just changing the way we interpret it.

Comment: The template works basically the same as the "format" string does in some C standard library functions, like printf(). It tells pack() or unpack() _how_ to convert the data. So "s*" means "treat the second argument as a signed 16-bit value". That's just the "s"; the "*" tells pack()/unpack() that there are a variable number of characters in the second arg string, so just take them all.

Comment: Ah okay I think I understand. It makes a lot of sense now. thanks Joe

Comment: For an example, if I would have used `pack('H*', $num)` above, $num would have been treated like a hexadecimal number. So `pack('H*', $num)` would've returned the actual hexadecimal value 0x1234, or 4660 in decimal. Likewise, `unpack('H*', $num)` would have again treated 1234 as the hexadecimal string 0x1234, and would have then interpreted it into ASCII, returning "31323334" (looking at your ASCII tables, you'd notice that "31" == "1" in ASCII, "32" == "2", etc.).